# How to group actors distributed across an akka cluster?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor

Is there a way to group actors distributed across an akka cluster, and set a maximum number of actors for each group?
What i am looking for is something like the akka's *role* for a node in the cluster, but more fine grained, i.e. Roles for actors distributed across nodes.

Thanks

Comment: Is cluster sharding what you are looking for? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/cluster-sharding.html

Comment: Possibly. Can actors in a single shard region be distributed across the cluster? Is it sensible to have thousands of shard regions in a cluster of few nodes? Can the maximum number of actors in a shard region be capped? Can the actors be started automatically? Overall I think sharding might be a bit heavy. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to cap the number of shard regions per node?